# Mongoose transaction for find().session(session) gives IllegalOperation error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm unable to find a solution for this issue.

I wanted to get all Users with 'Admin' privilege and wanted to send them notification. What I've tried so far using Mongoose transaction is as follows:

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
session.startTransaction();

const systemRole = await SystemRole.find(
    {
      isActive: true,
      roleName: "Admin",
    },
 ).session(session);

const adminUsers = await User.find(
      {
        isActive: true,
        systemRoles: { $contains: systemRole },
      },
    ).session(session);
```

There is `systemRole` array inside User schema which has a type of `ObjectId`.

I don't know what I've missed here but this keeps sending me the following error:

> ```
> errors:
> code: 20
> codeName: "IllegalOperation"
> ```

I've followed [this post](https://gist.github.com/aeciolevy/0962ad4ee45f340cbac0622e089030b3).

Finding `systemRoles` works fine without the session but I wanted it to be in a transaction so that if one fails it should be aborted.

Comment: Can you try changing `$contains: systemRole[0].roleName ` ?

Comment: @HarshitRastogi I think that's not the issue, I've checked by removing the entire `adminUsers` code and yet got exact same error message.

Comment: Try using seesion like this `await coll1.insertOne({ abc: 1 }, { session });`

Comment: But I've seen posts that you can also use session for `find()` query

Comment: yes, you can use for find query, just try using the session as mentioned in above comment

Comment: `await SystemRole.findOne( { isActive: true,roleName: "System_Admin", },  {session}
    );` ...  This gives `error:{}` with no message at all

Comment: Please also check [this](https://prnt.sc/1rhhrch) mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/)

Comment: @HarshitRastogi I've updated `mongoose` to the latest version and now I'm facing `user findone buffering timed out after 10000ms` issue

Comment: are you getting the results from `systemRole`?

Comment: Not really, still hang on the same error